# I have scheduled a periodic work by calling the enqueueUniquePeriodicWork() method. How to get result?

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager

I'm using WorkManager 1.0.1 and I have a question. 
For example, I have scheduled a periodic work by the following code:

```
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("work", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, myPeriodicWorkRequest)
```

How do I figure out if this request was "declined" due to the work with the same name had already been scheduled or if everything was okay and the work was sucessfully scheduled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the myPeriodicWorkRequest id value to retrieve the work information.
For instance, you could call `WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(myPeriodicWorkRequest.id)` in order to get a live data for observing changes in the scheduled work.

Answer (score 0):

Enqueuing your unique work using [`ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy#KEEP) means that you are asking WorkManager to enqueue your WorkRequest only if there isn't another WorkRequest, connected to the same unique name, in a ["non-final" state](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/states-and-observation).

If you need to always enqueue the new WorkRequest you should use [``ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy#REPLACE).

If you think that you need to know if the new WorkRequest has been enqueued or not you are probably trying to shift to much of your application context into WorkManager.